# Why does this SQL "UPSERT" affect two rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to write an upsert, and when I run these two queries sequentially:

```
// The numbers here are arbitrary, but id matches one already existing in db. 
SET @id = 1069, @exportid = null, @photoid = 11223344;

INSERT INTO student (id_number, exportid, photoid) VALUES (@id, @exportid, @photoid)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE exportid = @exportid, photoid = @photoid;
```

and it hits the update and makes some changes, I get "2 rows affected". Why isn't it just one (If it hits the insert I get 1 row affected as expected)?

The CREATE statement for the table, with a bunch of non-key columns redacted:

```
CREATE TABLE  `demo`.`student` (
  `id_number` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `exportid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photoid` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_number`),
  KEY `EXPORTID` (`exportid`),
  KEY `NAME` (`last_name`,`student`,`id_number`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Do you have multiple unique keys on the table?

Comment: @Uueerdo My bad. I specify the id_number earlier to refer to one specific id. Let me edit post.

Comment: How did you create the table? Is `id_number` a Primary / unique key?

Comment: @Sirmyself Yup, it is Primary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and
>   0 if an existing row is set to its current values.

from the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)